# JAVA Split huge file into multiparts ZIP. How to?

Tags: java, stream, zip

In my application I have to send XLS reports by email, but if the file is larger than 10 MB I have to split this file into multipart ZIP-s and send as a separate emails with attachments (one email - one ZIP part). If anyone knows library that will help me do it? Is there any easy way in Java?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try [Apache Commons Compress](http://commons.apache.org/compress/examples.html) and [Apache Commons IO](http://commons.apache.org/io/).

You can create the zip like this (from the example documentation):

```
ZipArchiveEntry entry = new ZipArchiveEntry(name);
entry.setSize(size);
zipOutput.putNextEntry(entry);
zipOutput.write(contentOfEntry);
zipOutput.closeArchiveEntry();
```

You can pair this with [FileUtils.readFileToByteArray( File file );](http://commons.apache.org/io/api-release/org/apache/commons/io/FileUtils.html#readFileToByteArray%28java.io.File%29) and then loop through the byte array writing out your zip files.